# Mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Working my way through the following problem:

#### Problem

> Suppose that $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive events of an
> experiment.  Show that if independent trials of this experiment are
> performed,  then $E$ will occur before $F$ with probability
> $\frac{ P( E)}{P( E) + P( F)}.$

I have the following come up with the following solution:

#### Solution

> Since
> $P( E^c) = P( F)$
> Therefore
> $\frac{ P( E)}{ P( E) + P( F)} = \frac{ P( E)}{ 1 - P( F) + P( F)} = \frac{ P( E)}{ 1} = P( E)$

But I am unsure if I am able to assume $P( E^c) = P( F)$ as a given?

As well, I am particularly confused by the answer in the solution manual which makes it's argument as follows:

#### Solution Manual

> If $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive events in an experiment,  then
> $P( E \cup F) = P( E) + P( F)$. We desire to compute the probability
> that $E$ occurs before $F$ , which we will denote by $p$. To compute
> $p$ we condition on the three mutually exclusive events $E$, $F$ , or
> $(E \cup F )^c$. This last event are all the outcomes not in $E$ or
> $F$. Letting the event $A$ be the event that $E$ occurs before $F$, we
> have that
>
> $p = P( A|E) P( E) + P( A|F) P(F ) + P( A|(E \cup F )^c) P( (E \cup F )^c)$
>
> $P( A|E) = 1$
>
> $P( A|F) = 0$
>
> $P( A|(E \cup F)^c) = p$
>
> since if neither $E$ or $F$ happen the next experiment will have $E$
> before $F$ (and thus event $A$ with probability $p$). Thus we have
> that
>
> $p = P( E) + p P( (E \cup F)^c)$
>
> $= P( E) + p (1 − P( E \cup F))$
>
> $= P( E) + p (1 − P( E) − P( F))$
>
> Solving for $p$ gives
>
> $p = \frac{ P( E)}{ P( E) + P( F)}$
>
> as we were to show.

Specifically his statement

> since if neither $E$ or $F$ happen the next experiment will have $E$
> before $F$ (and thus event $A$ with probability $p$)

Comment: They mean: If neither $E$ or $F$ happens on the first trial, then the game starts over.

Comment: So we are able to treat the experiment as if only mutually exclusive events $E$ and $F$ exist and my solutions is valid correct?

Comment: No, that is a separate issue. In fact, there is no need to assume that $E$ and $F$ are *exhaustive*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To determine the probability that $E$ occurs before $F$, we can ignore
all the (independent) trials on which neither $E$ nor $F$ occurred,
that is, $(E\cup F)^c$ occurred, since we are going to repeat the
experiment until one of $E$ and $F$ *does* occur.  So, look at the
trial of the experiment on which one of $E$ and $F$ *has* occurred
*for the very first time*.
We are *given* that on this trial, the event $E \cup F$ *has* occurred.
But, we don't yet know which of the two has occurred. So, given the
knowledge that $E \cup F$ has occurred, what is the *conditional*
probability that it was $E$ that occurred (and so $E$ occurred before $F$
since this is the first time we have seen either $E$ or $F$)?

$$P(E \mid (E \cup F)) = \frac{P(E(E \cup F))}{P(E \cup F)}
= \frac{P(E \cup EF)}{P(E) + P(F) - P(EF)} 
= \frac{P(E)}{P(E)+P(F)}$$
since $P(EF) = P(\emptyset) = 0$.

---

Alternatively, let $G = (E\cup F)^c = E^c \cap F^c$ be the event that neither
$E$ nor $F$ occurs on a trial of the experiment. Note that 
$P(G) = 1 - P(E) - P(F)$.  Then, the event $E$ occurs
before $F$ if and only if one of the following compound events occurs:

$$
E, (G, E), (G, G, E), \ldots, (\underbrace{G, G, \ldots, G,}_{n-1} E), \ldots
$$

where $(\underbrace{G, G, \ldots, G,}_{n-1} E)$ means $n-1$ trials on which $G$
occurred and then $E$ occurred on the $n$-th trial.  The desired probability
is thus

$$P(E ~\text{before}~ F) = P(E) + P(G)P(E) + [P(G)]^2P(E) + \cdots
= \frac{P(E)}{1 - P(G)} = \frac{P(E)}{P(E)+P(F)}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is incorrect. If $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive, it means that $E \cap F = \emptyset$, therefore $F \subseteq E^c$; and therefore, $P(F) \color{red}{\le} P(E^c)$.

You are not interpreting **independent trials of the experiment** correctly. It might be helpful to consider an example. Suppose you are rolling a biased 6-faced die. Let $E$ denote the event that 1 or 2 turn up and $F$ denote the event that 3 or 4 turn up. Continue rolling the die until either $E$ or $F$ occur. What is the probability that $E$ occurs before $F$, that is what is the probability that you get 1 or 2 before you get 3 or 4 (in the repeated rolls of the die).

The statement

> since if neither $E$ or $F$ happen the next experiment will have $E$ before
> $F$ (and thus event $A$ with probability $p$)

means that if neither $E$ or $F$ happen, that is if 5 or 6 is rolled, we roll the die again. Since the rolls are independent, the probability of getting $E$ before $F$ in the future experiments is $p$.

**Rant**: This problem and its solution shows why students find probability confusing. The problem is stated very informally. In my opinion, a formal statement of the problem will remove some of the confuson.

Consider an experiment $\mathcal E_1$ with probability measure $P_1$. Let $E$ and $F$ be two events in $\mathcal E_1$. $P_1(E)$ denotes the probability that $E$ occurs in experiment $\mathcal E_1$. Similarly interpretation holds for $P_1(F)$.

Now consider another experiment $\mathcal E_2$, which represents infinite independent repetitions of the experiment $\mathcal E_1$. Let $P_2$ be the probability measure for events in $\mathcal E_2$.

Now consider an outcome $\omega$ of $\mathcal E_2$ that is a series of outcomes of $\mathcal E_1$. Let $\tau_E$ denote the first time $E$ occurs in $\omega$ (with $\tau_E = \infty$ if $E$ does not occur). Similarly, let $\tau_F$ denotes the first time $F$ occurs in $\omega$.  Let $A$ denote the event (**in $\mathcal E_2$**) that $\tau_E < \tau_F$. The question is asking you to show that

> $\displaystyle  P_{\color{red}2}(A) = \frac{ P_1(E) }{ P_1(E) + P_1(F) }$

Thus, the question is asking you to compare two different experiments. When you write $E^c \equiv F$, you were thinking in terms of experiment $\mathcal E_2$; but $E$ and $F$ are not events in $\mathcal E_2$; they are events in $\mathcal E_1$.

Comment: Since as you state in the context of your example > if neither $E$ or $F$ happen, that is if 5 or 6 is rolled, we roll the die again.  Approaching the problem as if $E^c \equiv F$ is therefore valid then, no?

Comment: $E^c = \{3,4,5,6\} \not\equiv \{3,4\} = F$

Comment: Yes but should ${5,6}$ occur we roll again, for the purposes of calculating the desired probability of this problem we disregard all events that do not exist in $E \cup F$ as they have no effect on the computation, therefore you are able to approach the problem as if $E^c \equiv F$, no?

Comment: Does my updated answer clarify this point?

Comment: You make good but points but when I write $E^c \equiv F$ I am doing so under the conditions of the problem which state that any occurrence of an event $\in E^c \cap F^c$ will simply be disregarded and therefore $E^c \equiv F$... $P( E)$ is the probability that an event $\in E$ will occur before an event $\in F$.  Similarly, $1 - P( E)$ is the event $P( E)$ does _not_ occur first, i.e. $E^c \equiv F$ as $1 - P( E) = P( F)$.

Comment: The event that $E$ does not occur first is (in my notaton) $A^c$. You cannot simply change the meaning of $E$ (which is an event in experiment $\mathcal E_1$). Perhaps the solution given by @DilipSarwate is close to what you are thinking: Think of the experiment in which _either_ $E$ or $F$ occur _for the first time_. What is the probability that the event that occurred was $E$.

Comment: Your comments have been most helpful and deserve votes from others!

Answer (score 1):

I think extreme simplification is need...

$P(E) and P(F)$ are complements for the Universe (U, U=1 in this case)
$P(E) + P(F) = 1$  //  corrected as mentioned by Aditya, sorry for my dyslexic!thing

$P(E) / ( P(E)+P(F) ) = 1 / 2$ Hence 
    probability of $E$ is $50\%$ (or $0.5$), 
    probability of restant set is the remaining $50\%$; 
    the remaining set is $F$ because $U=\{E, F\}$
    with the given data $P(E \text{ before } F) = P(F \text{ before }E)$.

Comment: If $P(E) = P(F) = 1$, then $E$ and $F$ cannot be mutually exclusive because $E \cup F \subset \Omega$, thus $P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F) \le P(\Omega) = 1$.

Comment: E and F are exclusive... when I say P(E) = P(F) = 1, I mean "wheight_of_P(E)" + "wheight_of_P(F)" is equal to 1(totality in probability)... without more information from the problem I assume that "E_is_complement_and_exclusive_of_F" and "F_is_complement_and_exclusive_of_E"... I've added parenteses to the answer for clarity...

Comment: Then you should assume $P(E) = P(F) = 0.5$

Comment: You're right, what I wanted to say is : 
    P(E) = P(F)  and  P(E) + P(F) = 1... thanks seeing it...

As per opposition to the other possibility which was : 
    P(E) <> P(F)  and  P(E) + P(F) = 1

in both cases :
    $P(E) \cap P(F) = \emptyset$
    and 
    $P(E) \cup P(F) = U$ (U=Universe or FullSet, 1 in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of using conditional probability.

Consider repeated experiments and let $Z_n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) be the result observed on the $n$-th experiment.
Denote the event of "$\textrm{E before F}$" by $B$ and its probability $\alpha$.

According to the law of total probability, we obtain

$$\alpha = P \{ B\} = \sum_{z} P \{B \mid Z_1 = z \} P \{ Z_1 = z \}$$

Now we have

$$P \{ B \mid Z_1 = E \} = 1, \quad P \{ B \mid Z_1 = F \} = 0.$$

If the first experiment results in anything other than $E$ or $F$, the problem is repeated in a statistically identical setting. That is,

$$P \{ B \mid Z_1 = z \} = \alpha, \forall z \neq E, F.$$

Therefore, we have

$$\alpha = P \{ Z_1 = E \} \times 1 + P \{ Z_1 = F \} \times 0 + \sum_{z \neq E,F} P \{ Z_1 = z \} \times \alpha \\ = P \{ Z_1 = E \} + [1 - P \{ Z_1 = E \} - P \{ Z_1 = F \}] \alpha$$

Solving this equation, we get

$$\alpha = \frac{P \{ Z_1 = E \}}{P \{ Z_1 = E \} + P \{ Z_1 = F \}}.$$