# mutually exclusive events where one event occurs before the other

Tags: probability

This question has been asked before. Here is the link: [Mutually exclusive events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161485/mutually-exclusive-events)

Here is the description to the problem:

> Let E and F be mutually exclusive events in the sample space of an
>   experiment. Suppose that the experiment is repeated until either event
>   E or event F occurs. What does the sample space of this new super
>   experiment look like? Show that the probability that event E occurs
>   before event F is P(E)/ [P(E) + P(F)]. 
>   **Hint:** 
>   Argue that the probability that the original experiment is performed n times and E
>   appears on the nth time is P(E)×(1−p)n−1, n = 1, 2, . . . , where p =
>   P(E) + P(F). Add these probabilities to get the desired answer.

It appears to me that this is an example of a "Geometric Distribution". I am trying to solve this using the hint given, but I know not how to proceed, especially with adding up the probabilities as suggested.

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that at least one of $E$ or $F$ has positive probability, then with probability $1$, one of them will occur eventually.

Then $P(E|(E\cup F))=\frac{P(E\cap(E\cup F))}{P(E\cup F)}=\frac{P(E)}{P(E)+P(F)}$

Comment: Could you please explain your choice of answer? Why did you pick up $P(E|E \cup F)$

Comment: @Quester: Eventually $E$ or $F$ will occur (that's what we're waiting for in the process), and that event is $E\cup F$.  One way to think of it would be if someone else was doing the experiment, and after each trial that person told us: 'yes, $E$ or $F$ occurred'; or 'no, neither $E$ nor $F$ occurred'. Eventually the person would say 'yes', and we want to know the probability of that the eventual 'yes' would come from $E$ occurring, rather than from $F$ occurring.

Comment: @paw..Makes sense thank you